# Editing Style Delete not showing Delete Button

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a functioning "ToDo" list app and just adding a finishing touch. I am implementing a commitEditingStyle function as below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        toDoList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")
        toDoListTable.reloadData()
```

The app doesn't crash, no errors and it does 'appear' to swipe by moving to the left and then back to the right but no red DELETE button appears. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Frankeex, have you implemented tableViewCanEditRowAtIndexPath???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your constraints on your tableview. If none are set then the "Delete" button will show up outside of the current view (This can be shown in your UI debugger). So just constrain to leading and trailing view and Viola! Hope this helps.